# How to identify internal failures in a Windows service

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

We use a lot of custom Windows services in our applications. However, the one I'm currently working on has an infuriating problem: while the service keeps running, it simply stops functioning.

The Main method of the service is wrapped in a try/catch block, like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    IRepository rep = new Repository();
    ILogger log = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType().Name);

    TimeSpan loadWindowStart = new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0);
    TimeSpan loadWindowEnd = new TimeSpan(18, 0, 0);

    foreach (SuppressionLoad sl in rep.GetSuppressionLoads().ToList())
    {
        try
        {
            // do stuff
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // log error
        }
    }
}
```

The service also logs as it does stuff, and we can watch the logs fill up while it's busy.

Sometimes, however, the logs just stop. And activity elsewhere in the database suggests the entire service has stopped working. Checking in Services on the server, the service still shows a Status of "Started". It takes up almost zero system resources while it's in this state, although it's normally quite processor intensive. If you try and stop it, it just times out trying and, as far as we can tell, it never stops of its own accord. The process has to be killed in Task Manager.

There is nothing untoward in the log in the run up to these stalls. There is also nothing we can find in Event Viewer.

Since it doesn't log an error, I'm at a loss as to what's going on here, or what we can do to try and diagnose the fault from here. It's highly intermittent - it will often run for several days without problem before entering the state. What can we do to investigate what's going on?

Comment: sounds like you will need to look at the code for the Service, start using the debugger and step thru the code.. perhaps you may want to consider changing the way that you do logging.. maybe write directly to a log file or create a new log file every time.

Comment: @MethodMan Stepping through is fine, but this failure is so intermittent that it's not really a practical option.

Comment: well not much I can suggest then except for .. perhaps you are creating resources and not disposing of them correctly.. and what time of exception message are you trapping for .. etc..?

Comment: It sounds like the issue could be anywhere and doesn't necessarily have much to do with code provided.  One suggestion: when service hangs, attach a debugger and take a look at threads and where each one is. Questions to ask: are all the threads that I'm expecting there or are some gone or unaccounted for. Are threads stuck in a deadlock (I'm suspecting that's what's happening), and if so, on what resources.  Turn on detailed logging and sprinkle in more debug log statements to isolate where in code flow it last was and where it didn't make it to, and then keep narrowing down the location.

Comment: That sounds like a dead lock. You should be able to take a minidump using Task Manager, and analyze it in a debugger like WinDbg. WinDbg has commands to find lockups of synchronization objects (I believe `!locks` can do this).

Comment: Could it be that there is an error in the logging system? That one might not be catched in your try/catch block. Say there is a failure which breaks the server and it cannot be logged. Try logging a tick every x seconds and when the service fails take a look at the windows event log around the time of the last tick to see the system has maybe noticed something else.

Comment: @LB2 Thanks for that - stupidly, that approach hadn't occurred to me. If you want to refashion your comment into an answer, I'll give at an upvote at the least :)

Comment: @MattThrower, very kind of you and thank you.  Posted as answer and slightly expanded on (now that I don't have character limit :) ).

Answer (score 1):

Matt; Obscure problems such as these are difficult to find in the best of conditions - if your service happens to use threads (which I assume it does), it becomes tremendously more difficult and you can't rely on global try/catch.

A simple thing to try would be NBug (no association). It will catch un-handled exceptions and give you some info about them. I don't think it will get you enough though.

The general way to find these sorts of things is log, log, log. You have to be able to come as close to recreating the problem as possible - you need logs that tell your entry points into each method, the variable values, exception stack traces if hit, how long you spent in each method, etc. There are some really good tools out there for logging [some logging tools](http://www.dotnetlogging.com/) so I won't bother with recommending any. You can wrap your logging in a conditional compile switch so once you find your issue you won't suffer a performance hit when you turn it off.

Probably not the answer you wanted, but the only thing that has really worked for me over the years.

SteveJ

Comment: Not about what I wanted to hear, but what other people have found helpful. +1

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the issue could be anywhere and doesn't necessarily have much to do with code provided.

Suggestions on how to go about it

1. When service hangs, attach a debugger and take a look at threads and see where each one is.  You may need to rebuild and run a debug version of your solution so that debugger has necessary contextual symbol data. Questions to ask:

   1. Are all the threads that I'm expecting to be there are there, or are some gone or unaccounted for?
   2. Are threads stuck in a deadlock (I'm suspecting that's what's happening), and if so, on what resources.
2. Turn on detailed logging and sprinkle in more debug log statements to isolate where in code flow it last was and where it didn't make it to, and then keep narrowing down the location. Consider logging contextual data so that when you isolate problematic line or code block, you have context to try to understand why odd behavior takes place.  Just be mindful of logging sensitive information (i.e. passwords, PII, etc.)
3. With full credit to IInspectable's comment, you can try to take a full dump of the process ([SysInternal's Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) or [ProcDump](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) let's you do that, or [Task Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/931673/how-to-create-a-user-mode-process-dump-file-in-windows-vista-and-in-windows-7)).  It tends to be quite an involved experience using the tool, but used right can give a lot of insight, and possibly find the issue on first occurrence.

Considering that it happens infrequently, and the field of what and where is wide open, it'll likely take a few iterations of having the problem trigger in order to narrow down the scope.

Comment: If you narrow down the scope but still can't see why, update your question and ping me - I'd be happy to help further.